# Rendering nested objects in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

New to Ember and I cannot figure out how to render nested options either via associated ember-data models or simply as json objects.

JSON looks like this:

```
 contact: {
        first_name,
        last_name,
        emails: [{email1...}, {email2...}]
 }
```

Looking for the easiest solution, I tried this in handlebars template:

```
{{#each emails}}
     ...
{{/each}}
```

Trying a more advanced solution, which will eventually be needed I created the following ember-data models:

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  first_name: DS.attr('string'),
  last_name: DS.attr('string'),
  company: DS.attr('string'),
  emails: DS.hasMany('Rainmaker.Email')
});

App.Email = DS.Model.extend({
  contact_id: DS.attr('number'),
  email_address: DS.attr('string'),
  emails: DS.belongsTo('Rainmaker.Contact')
});
```

Which seems to be working somewhat (App.Email:ember517 renders on the screen) but it looks like it's still trying to ping the server to get the email addresses and I've already got them lazy loaded.

I have no idea where to go next and greatly appreciate any guidance or links to documentation that I've overlooked. Thanks.

Comment: a = App.Contant.find(1); a_emails = a.get('emails'); should return an array of associated emails

Comment: What version of ember-data are you using? You might want to check out this commit: https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/b5d7c478e79aa9706e0196b8769b7ef67bb26fc4

Comment: Thank for the recommendation. I actually ended up taking a look at the documentation again and got my JSON response "sideloaded" like the docs suggest. So thanks again for pointing me back to the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 28. dec the Ember team has included support for embedded records. If you look at https://github.com/emberjs/data at about 1/3 of the page, it gives you some directions on this.

In your case, simply altering `emails: DS.hasMany('Rainmaker.Email')` to `emails: DS.hasMany('Rainmaker.Email',{embedded:true})` should do the trick according to the docs.